# Question on Regularity and infinitely descending sequences

Tags: logic, set-theory

I have a small question with regard to how exactly one goes about demonstrating that, through the Axiom of Regularity, there can be no infinitely descending sequences $x_0 \ni x_1 \ni \dots$ in ZF.

As I understand it, the argument might go so: Let $y = \{x_0, x_1, \dots\}$. By Regularity, there must be some $z \in y$ with $z \cap y = \emptyset$. However, as $y$ contains only those $x_i$, we can consider some arbitrary $x_k \in y$ and see that $x_{k+1} \in x_k, y$, hence $x_k \cap y \neq \emptyset$. Thus, as no $z \in y$ verifies $z \cap y = \emptyset$ (contradicting Regularity), there cannot be such an infinitely descending sequence (or chain) $x_0 \ni x_1 \ni \dots$.

Now, my small question/doubt is, how exactly are we securing the existence of the set $y = \{x_0, x_1, \dots\}$? For finitely many $x_0, \dots, x_n$, one can always construct the set $\{x_0, \dots, x_n\}$ via the Axiom of Pairing and Union so: $\{x_0, \dots, x_n, x_{n+1}\} = \{x_0, \dots, x_n\} \cup \{x_{n+1}\}$; but clearly the existence of some set containing infinitely many sets/elements is not so easily ascertained, no?

Now, as I understand it, the matter is actually so: The *sequence* $x_0, \dots, x_n$ is, formally speaking, a *function* $f : \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow V$. Hence, given some such function (sequence), we can secure the existence of its image-set/the set containing the sequential elements by the Axiom of Replacement.

So, formally stated, the "no infinitely descending sequence exists" claim might actually be stated as "no function $f : \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow V$ exists so that $f(n) \ni f(n + 1)$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$," no? Here "$\mathbb{N}$" might be introduced as a (unique) constant secured by the Axiom of Infinity.

Thus, if that is indeed the case, I know understand how one might actually secure the existence of the set $y = \{x_0, x_1, \dots\}$. However, the next doubt appears: does that not then reduce our possible $x_0, x_1, \dots$ to only those expressible/"accessible" via some first-order functional formula? That is, we can only be considering sequences, hence functions, hence first-order functional formulae, and their respective image-sets, but those might well not cover the whole of all possible sets that "are there," no?

Am I to interpret this, then, as the following: ZF proves no first-order functional formula ranging over $\mathbb{N}$ can be so that $f(n) \ni f(n + 1)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. There may, however, be infinitely descending sequences of sets not expressible as image-sets of such first-order functional formulae within the "whole" of the universe/model being considered? I suppose such could potentially make sense if one "expanded" into non-standard models? Similar to how one can find infinitely descending sequences proving non-well-orderedness when considering non-standard extensions of the standard model of PA, no?

I know such are many questions/doubts at once possibly, but any help in clarifying these matters would be much, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZF proves the *sentence* "there is no function $f:\mathbb N\to V$ such that for all $n\in \mathbb N,$ $f(n+1)\in f(n)".$

Functions in ZF are just defined as sets of ordered pairs... we can talk about them in general, quantify over them, etc. without needing to resort to schemes of formulas defining them in the metatheory.

The proof goes like you say: if such an $f$ existed, its range $X=\{f(n): n\in \mathbb N\}$ would violate regularity, since for all $n,$ $f(n+1)\in X\cap f(n).$

There's no more reason to worry about 'what this means' than to worry about literally anything ZF proves. It's a first order theory... of course it only controls the first order properties of its models. Such is life.

But if we're on that subject, this does mean it is completely possible for there to be non-well-founded models of ZF (and actually it's inevitable if any models exist at all by a simple compactness argument). Such a model's membership relation does have infinite descending membership chains... in fact it can even be the case that the model's $\mathbb N$ has infinite descending chains, and thus is isomorphic externally to a nonstandard model of arithmetic. Just as it's fine with PA for the universe to look externally like a nonstandard model of arithmetic  as long as the nonstandardness is undetectable internally, it's fine with ZF for a model to not be externally well-founded.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I believe I possess a better understanding now because of it... Might I then ask: would the statement here proved by ZF be, formally speaking, $\nexists x \ [x \ \text{is a function} \ x : \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow V \land \forall y \in \mathbb{N} \ (x(y + 1) \in x(y))]$?

Comment: @Sho yes. (And you could expand out the definitions further of course.)